# C++ basic constructors/vectors problem (1 constructor, 2 destructors)

Tags: c++

Question is probably pretty basic, but can't find out what's wrong (and it leads to huge of memleaks in my app):

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass() { cout << "constructor();\n"; };
    MyClass operator= (const MyClass& b){ 
        cout << "operator=;\n"; return MyClass(); 
    };
    ~MyClass() { cout << "destructor();\n"; };
};

main() {
    cout << "1\n";
    vector<MyClass> a;
    cout << "2\n";
    MyClass b;
    cout << "3\n";
    a.push_back(b);
    cout << "4\n";
}
```

The output is:

```
1
2
constructor();
3
4
destructor();
destructor();
```

1. Why are there 2 destructors?
2. If it's because a copy is created to be inserted into vector - how come "operator=" is never called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the b object gets pushed onto the vector a copy is made, but not by the `operator=()` you have - the compiler generated copy constructor is used.

When the main() goes out of scope, the `b` object is destroyed and the copy in the vector is destroyed.

Add an explicit copy constructor to see this:

```
MyClass( MyClass const& other) {
    cout << "copy ctor\n";
};
```

Comment: Is there a way to make that "copy" mechanism either use my operator= or (better yet) at least call a constructor?

Comment: You can write your own copy constructor, mirroring what is done by the operator=.

Comment: It calls copy constructor, just implement it and you'll see.

Comment: I get answer when the vector is ´vector<MyClass>´. But I am seeing the same behavior ( 1 ctor and 2 dtor ) when i have a ´vector<sharedptr<MyClass>>´. Why is that? Does a copy of MyClass gets created even if i have a vector of sharedptrs?

sharedprt<> is ref-counted smart ptr.

Comment: @Gautam - you would need to show some code for me to discuss what might be happening intelligently. It sounds like maybe you have a local/automatic variable (like `b` in the question), and are pushing a `shared_ptr<>` to it onto the vector.  In that case you have a bug that 2 entities think they own the object and are responsible for destroying it. One is the 'scope' which owns local/automatic variables, and the other is the `shared_ptr`. You cannot pass ownership of a local/automatic to a `shared_ptr` (not entirely true, see the next comment).

Comment: You could create a `shared_ptr` to a local/automatic and prevent double-destruction by creating it with a 'null deleter' (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/libs/smart_ptr/sp_techniques.html#static). But if you do that you have to take care that the lifetime of the `shared_ptr` to that object not extend beyond the lifetime of the automatic variable.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to log all copies and constructions you should add an explicit copy constructor so that the compiler doesn't create one for you.

```
MyClass( const MyClass& )
{
    cout << "Copy constructor\n";
}
```

You can, in your copy constructor, call your assignment operator. It is a reasonably common way of implementing things, however with your definition of operator=, this may have serious problems.

You have an unconventional implementation of operator=. operator= should return a *reference* to the class on which it is called (to enable proper chaining), but you return a new class instance by value. This means that if you tried to call operator= from your copy constructor you may well end up with infinite recursion. Try this operator= instead:

```
MyClass& operator=( const MyClass& )
{
    cout << "operator=\n";
    return *this;
}
```

When defining an assignment operator you should always consider the possibility that the parameter and *this may refer to the same object and ensure that the definition of the operator won't have any unintended effects in this scenario.

Comment: +1, also, you should mention that a self-assignment check should be made at the beginning of the operator= method.

Comment: This assignment operator is safe for self-assignment so there is no need to perform it. Many assignment operators are safe for self-assignment (e.g. those implemented with copy and swap), those that require it are often not exception safe (see Herb Stutter's excellent Exceptional C++). For these reasons, I prefer to add the check only when necessary.

Comment: Ok, I said you should because it's a good practice (ie future modification of the method). That's all.

Comment: Possibly, but better practice (IMHO) would be to maintain the assignment operator's inherent exception safety and self-assignment safety in future modifications. I would consider needing to add an explicit check something of a compromise.

Comment: @Nick: The copy/swap idiom does not require a test for self, and test for self is now considered bad practice as its existence indicates you are not using copy/swap. Copy and swap is the preferred technique because it provides the "Strong Exception Guarantee". Note. I use copy and swap and test for self (but not because assignment to self is bad. But because it is an optimization technique. Saying that it is not required though).

Comment: @Martin York: Do you have a (brief) example of where checking for a self-assignment as an optimization made a positive difference? I understand the rationale but I've never actually had a situation like that myself. If I did I would be tempted to look at the algorithm or process that was causing multiple self-assignments and see if there was an improvement or alternative that would help at that level, rather than in the class being operated on.