# mismatch in constructors/destructors count

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ basic constructors/vectors problem (1 constructor, 2 destructors)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992435/c-basic-constructors-vectors-problem-1-constructor-2-destructors)

I have got the code:

```
#include <iostream>
class A   
{    
public:    
    A() { std::cout<<"A::A"<<std::endl; }    
    ~A() { std::cout<<"A::~A"<<std::endl; }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B(){ std::cout<<"B::B"<<std::endl; }
    ~B(){ std::cout<<"B::B"<<std::endl; }
};

void Func( A a ){}

int main()
{
    B b;
    Func(b);
}
```

in VS2010EE output will be:

```
A::A
B::B
A::~A //why twice? Once on gcc!
A::~A
B::~B
A::~A
```

But, when we have copy constructor, output is:

```
A::A
B::B
A::A(copy)
A::~A
B::~B
A::~A
```

Comment: You always have a copy cosnstructor. If you don't declare one yourself but use it implicitly, the compiler will define one for you and the compiler provided one won't log to `std::cout`.

Comment: `~B` should print `"B::~B"`, not `"B::B"`.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in the A destructor and you should see where it's being called from.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: thanks, this pops often and yet I could not find a duplicate :/

Comment: @Artem: **Beware** you pass a `B` to a function expected a `A` by copy, exposing yourself to object-slicing (ie, only the `A` part of your instance is passed).

Comment: @CharlesBailey : Not sure it's a dupe: Why is the A destructor invoked *three* times? I could understand two (one for the temp A param, and one for the original object...)

Comment: @Roddy: If you don't add logging to a user defined copy constructor you can't see the copies being made. That's why I linked to the duplicate question which answers the title ("mismatch in ctor/dtor count") which is entirely due to having an implicitly defined constructor without any logging. In this case, One `A` is made as part of `b`, another is made converting `b` to type `A` in the function call and another is made copy-initializing the parameter from this temporary as the parameters is passed by value. The temporary may be elided but evidently isn't in one case.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: OK, but why would adding a user-defined copy constructor reduce the # of temporary objects, and hence destructions?

Comment: It's the slicing problem, as in my answer below: one copy makes the slice, one is used to copy the slice into the function frame. It seems like when you add a copy constructor, VS's compiler infers something about the semantics of the call you are making and uses your constructor to make just one copy directly from the B object.

Comment: @Roddy: I don't know; I have no knowledge of the compiler internals. I just know that a temporary is allowed but may be elided. Why the compiler in question sometimes elides it is beyond my knowledge. I don't even know whether optimizations are being used.

Answer (score 0):

That's a bit unfortunate. VS should avoid that second copy; are all optimizations on? Presumably, it's calling a copy constructor on the `A` portion of `b` to create the argument (ie slicing it), then copying that object onto the stack again for the function call. (In the first example, your constructor for `A` isn't being called because the generated copy constructor doesn't print output.) When you provide a copy constructor, it must create the copy directly on the stack.

Comment: That copy cannot be elided now, can it?

Comment: I've tried several optimization settings - no changes!

Comment: 'then copying that object onto the stack' : So where would it have put the first copy-constructed object, then?

Comment: (Good point Roddy; I meant the function frame rather than the scope's stack frame.) @Martino: one of the two copies can if gcc is doing it, unless it's doing something non-conformant. You would expect it to be possible to generate a constructor that copies directly to the stack; possibly VS's idea of correct semantics has some reason for disallowing this, but I can't think immediately what it might be.

Comment: PS. "Presumably": I use VS and gcc in my job, but I'm guessing at the internals of VS in particular.

Comment: I cant understand a profit of second copy creation. I think it is redundant. Why no copy elision?

Comment: I don't think there is any profit, but neither is there anything that would forbid it. In either case doing either one or two copies is perfectly legal. I'd suspect that MSVC special-cases the trivial copy constructor and somehow misses the possibility to merge the two operations.

Answer (score 0):

You're not counting all the constructors. In the first case, the copy constructor is invoked to create a copy of the object when calling `Func` (because the function takes its parameter by value).

When you don't define a copy constructor yourself, the compiler will generate one for you. And the compiler-generated copy constructor doesn't print anything out, so it doesn't figure in your output.

Comment: The quistion is why second copy ceated when used compiler generated copy-ctor. One copy enough.

Comment: Because you create two copies. First you create one instance in `main`, and then you pass that instance to `Func`, which, because it takes its parameter by value, creates a copy of it. That copy *could* be optimized away by the compiler, but when you read the code naively, you tell it to create an instance of the class, and then create a copy of that instance.

Comment: "Because you create two copies. First you create one instance in main" - the last lines of output are corresponding for object in main.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're effectively asking this:

> Why does VS2010 create an *additional* temporary when I have no copy
>   constructor?

The only answer I have is 'because it's allowed to'. It seems that it gets optimised away when you're using gcc, and also gets optimised away when you provide a user-defined copy constructor.

The behaviour is a little odd, but it's perfectly compliant. If all C++ compilers performed identically, we'd only need one compiler...